# React setState updates state differently accoring to the value inside of it

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand how setState of useState hook works.

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const increase1 = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    setCount(count + 1);
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const increase2 = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  };

  console.log(count);

  return <button onClick={increase1}>Increase</button>;
};
```

As you can see, when the button is clicked, state `count` is updated.

What I want to know is why function `increase1` and `increase2` working differently.

When the button is clicked several times with `increase1`, the count is increased 1, 2, 3 order. However when `increase2` is assigned, the count state is updated 3, 6, 9 order.

Why the value of updated state is different?

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-banzai-3rcr49?file=/src/Counter.js

Comment: in `increase1`, say `count = 3`, you call `setCount(4): setCount(4); setCount(4)` - are you starting to see the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on React official document:

> React batches state updates. It updates the screen after all the event
> handlers have run and have called their set functions.

Because of this, let's say the count = 0,  the value inside the first example `increase1` is always 0 between each setCount call, no matter how many times you call it.

However, in your second example, `(count) => count + 1` is an **updater function**, React will store the final result correctly in this case because it actually updates the count in between the calls.

your particular example is explained further more here:
https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates

Another worth reading article about this mechanism behind the scene:
https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot#rendering-takes-a-snapshot-in-time